# using paulmillr/noble-secp256k1 with deno deploy

Tags: typescript, deno, secp256k1, deno-deploy

I have this line in my file: `import * as secp256k1 from "npm:@noble/secp256k1";`

It works fine locally (`deno run`)

When I try to deno deploy, it cannot find the module.

I read this is because deno deploy doesn't yet support `npm:`.

To circumvent it I tried using `import * as secp256k1 from "https://deno.land/x/secp256k1/mod.ts"`, but this doesn't work locally. I'm getting

```
error: Relative import path "crypto" not prefixed with / or ./ or ../
If you want to use a built-in Node module, add a "node:" prefix (ex. "node:crypto").
    at https://deno.land/x/secp256k1@1.7.1/index.ts:6:29
```

how can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `/x/secp256k1` says:

> To use the module with Deno, you will need import map

In this case, you will need to polyfill node's crypto. In the future this will be done using `node:crypto`, but for now deploy does not support this and you must use `https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/node/crypto.ts`.

Your import map should look something like:

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "crypto": "https://deno.land/std@0.177.0/node/crypto.ts"
  }
}
```

Here is an example of using import maps with deploy (it's just how you would expect): https://github.com/satyarohith/import_map

Comment: thanks! I knew it was something simple. I will just add to other readers that this needs to be in `deno.json` in the root of working directory.